# Object no longer instance of Class after adding to Bull queue

Tags: javascript, class, object, fastify, bull-queue

In the `handler` of my [Fastify](https://www.fastify.io/) route, I'm adding to my [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) queue an object of a class. In the queue's process method, this object is no longer an instance of the class. Is this normal or am I missing some (or a lot) of the basics?

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
const Queue = require('bull');
let addQueue = new Queue('Add', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379');

...

addQueue.process(function(job, done){
  console.log(job.data.dataObj instanceof ClasssDefinedSomwhereElse);
}

...

fastify.route({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/',
  ...
  handler: async (request, reply) => {
    if(isFirstRequest) {
      classObj = new ClasssDefinedSomwhereElse();
      isFirstRequest = false;
    } else {
      console.log(classObj instanceof ClasssDefinedSomwhereElse);
      addQueue.add({dataObj: classObj});
    }
```

`addQueue.add({dataObj: classObj});` or `addQueue.add(classObj);` makes no difference.
The `handler` prints `true` & the `process` method prints `false`. Why is this?

What I'm eventually trying to do is, in the `process` method, call a method of the class using the object that I've just passed in. I'm not from a Javascript background so I think I might've missed something basic. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, the `class`, is not the same as `class` in Object-Oriented Programming.
The class is just syntactic sugar for the [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

So what is happening in your software is that:

- add a class instance to the bull queue
- bull will serialize the object in redis (depending on the [`toString()`](https://dev.to/adamcoster/how-to-stringify-class-instances-in-javascript-and-express-js-co4#:%7E:text=stringify()%20function%20on%20an,a%20plain%20object%20for%20stringifying.) implementation)
- bull will run in async the queue, fetching the **string** data from redis and parsing it to an object (like running `JSON.parse(aJsonString)`

In this process, there is no information about the `ClasssDefinedSomwhereElse` (like it would be in a class serialization in Java).
So you need to create a new instance of that class, based on the simple JSON that Bull is fetching.